# If I stop a long running postgresql DELETE USING query , does it rollback?

Tags: postgresql

I have a long running 319h postgresql DELETE USING query. I think at this point that the query should be terminated. What do you think are the risks of such operation and if it would rollback.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhap you can try reading this post
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/libpq-cancel.html

Comment: I'm thing of using pg_terminate_backend I don't want to rollback.

Comment: `pg_terminate_backend()` **will** rollback the transaction. A single statement is **always** atomic. Either everything it does, succeeds or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If it hasn't been committed, then there are no issues. Maybe a hung transaction that has to be killed from the DBA side.

Comment: No it's not hanging the query moves data from one big table to another. I don't want the rollback operation to take as much time consuming the precious resources I have.

Comment: @sa-mao a rollback in Postgres is pretty much without costs.

Comment: @sa-mao If you still want to do the operation, then try doing it parts. For example delete and commit after ever 10,000 records.